# Multiple filter query iusing php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, filter, isset

I have 12 "values" that can be assigned to customers - these are all stored in the database against the customer id - how do you go about writing a query to select all customers that have specific values assigned to them from a specific array of customers. These values are to be selected via a checkbox. I imagine it's some sort of nested if(isset) query ?

Comment: `isset()` is not the answer here. You should do the filtering in the database and return only the rows you want. For that we'd need to see your schema.

Comment: Hi Dave, we'll need a bit more info to answer this. But topline you should be able to achieve this with a HTML form that posts the filter values back to a PHP file where you handle the MySQL query. You can check that the filter value is !empty and if it isn't then add a WHERE clause to the query. If you have multiple filters you can have a $where array and then implode the conditions with and ' AND '.